# Lizmap very very slow loading data

Tags: qgis-plugins, lizmap, repository

Can someone tell me what is wrong when lizmap is loading data.
To load the data it takes about 150 seconds to load.
I found where it takes a long time...

[image: loading repository]

Or it does not load at all.
[image: no loading]

If it not loads then I get this error:

> An error occurred while loading this map. Some necessary resource may temporarily be unavailable. Please try again later.
> Go back to the home page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you use the last version of the Lizmap plugin? There are now many hints to improve the QGIS and Lizmap project's performance.

Comment: Indeed Nicolas, I use the last Lizmap server plugin  v2.8.1. Lizmap web client v3.6.7

Comment: Everytime you see a 500 error, you must check logs on the server. (ngninx/apache, PostgreSQL, QGIS server, Lizmap etc) There is an error on the server side. Mainly, you should check QGIS server logs, because you say it's slow to open the project : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes  Related to the version of the plugin, I guess Nicolas was talking about the plugin in QGIS Desktop.